# How to fix this problem while modeling a sphere from default cube?

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers

[image: I have made a sphere from default cube. In OBJECT MODE I have applied subdivision surface modifier and shaded smooth effect on cube to make a perfect sphere . But when I go into EDIT MODE to add loop cuts on a sphere, the shape of the sphere has became distorted even I have also enabled " Adjust Cage " in subdivision surface modifier. Image 1]

2. When adding loop cuts on a sphere. the shape has became distorted.
   [image]

Comment: it is what supposed to happen, you are flattening the shape with this additional edge, if you want to subdivide your cube but want to keep a spherical shape, the easiest way is to right click > Subdivide, then in the Operator box (bottom left of the 3D view) choose a Smoothness value of 1

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem there. Everything is working as intended. Loop cuts change the resulting form of surface subdivision. If input geometry had no result on subdivision surface modifier, it would be absolutely no good for modelling because you could not make different forms with it. I would suggest looking for the right technique to model what you want to model instead of trying to 'fix' a technique intended for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Although the behavior is as expected... If you want to add more geometry just as you did but still keep the sphere shape you can add a Modifier --> Cast as well and that will do it.